# CakePHP 3 - Create multiselect dropdown list

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, cakephp-3.0, dropdownbox

Using CakePHP 3 framework.

First of all, I don't know if this is possible.

**What I have now**

- Multiselect checkbox list.

**Example**

- Bikes 1 *checkbox*
- Bikes 2 *checkbox*
- Bikes 3 *checkbox*
- Cars 1 *checkbox*
- Cars 2 *checkbox*

The user is now allowed to select al 5 items.

**TODO**

- Users many-many relation with Vehicles
- Users is allowed to select one per group.

**Example TODO (my idea)**

- Dropdown bikes [
  Bikes 1, Bikes 2, Bikes 3
  ]
- Dropdown cars [ Cars 1, Cars 2 ]

The user needs to be only allowed to choose one per group.

Is it possible to achieve this by one array?

**EDIT**

Is it possible to group a list, like the example above, of radiobuttons?

Comment: Just a quick thought: Maybe you have to step back and think again about your database setup. You want to group your Vehicles, how would you do this by table relations? One vehicle belongs to a vehicle group, a vehicle group can have many vehicles. Then you can use this vehicle group table to catch your vehicles grouped and... well keep thinking, how you can use it ;) As mentioned only a quick thought...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look further.